# Crazy UTF-8 entry in a kotlin class' constant pool

Tags: java, class, kotlin, class-constants

When examining the content of a .class file from a Kotlin source (just "Hello World", nothing else) I found an UTF-8 string within the constant pool that is (a) not used anywhere and (b) with strange content.

Can any tell me what this is?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the content of `kotlin.Metadata` annotation. It is coded with Protobuf and used by both compiler and Kotlin-Reflect.

Kotlin uses `String` instead of `byte[]` because class format is very wasteful at storing arrays.

When you are not using Kotlin-Reflect, metadata is unused and can be removed by ProGuard.